# Taking screenshot of android returning Null?

Tags: android

I want to take screenshot of the screen of my **Rooted** device ( not just of particular activity but of **whole screen** ) with this code -

```
try {

 Process sh = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su", null,null);
            OutputStream  os = sh.getOutputStream();
            os.write(("/system/bin/screencap -p " + ""+mpath).getBytes("ASCII"));
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            sh.waitFor();
     } catch (Exception e)
      {
         Log.e("TAG_Err", "Error: "+e);
       }
```

where

`mpath= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString() + "/screenshots.png";`

now trying to display it with -

```
        try     
            {
            Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(""+mpath);
            ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            image.setImageBitmap(bMap);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("TAG_DISPLAY_ERR","error : "+e);
            }`
```

permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

But Image is not being dosplayed as it is saying -
Unable to decode Stream - java.io.FileNotFound exception .. I searched in my sdcard also , there is no file/image with name screenshots.png .

Why that ?
what is wrong with this code ?
what should I do ?

Comment: Directly set PATH like  `Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mpath);`

Comment: @ Simple Plan : thnks for quick response.. I tried it, but it din't work - still getting same result ..

Comment: @Simple plan you are right but the problem occuring while saving the file..

Answer (score 0):

To save your file you can use

```
      OutputStream fOut = null;
                    File file = new File(directoyname,imagename);
                        fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);

                    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 85, fOut);
                        fOut.flush();
                        fOut.close();

            MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(),file.getAbsolutePath(),file.getName(),file.getName());
```

Comment: @ Toppers - but how this code can take screenchot of current screen ?